# Appium Python screen-recorded video is sped-up

Tags: python, ios, automated-tests, appium, screen-recording

I'm developing automatic tests in **Appium Python** in an **iOS** environment and I need to record the execution of the tests.

**To start recording I use this method:**

```
driver.start_recording_screen()
```

**To stop recording and save the video, I use this one**

```
def save_video(video, filename):
     log_folder = name_of_log_folder
     video_path = f'{log_folder}/{filename}.mp4'
     with open(video_path, 'wb') as output_file:
         output_file.write(base64.b64decode(video))

save_video(driver.stop_recording_screen(), 'video_name')
```

The video is created and records all the steps, but I noticed that it is much faster than running the actual test (it even seems to be twice as fast!).

**To give you an idea of the timing:**

- Test execution time (real time): 32s
- Video duration time: 13s

**I really see the very fast loading animations and spinners that spin like crazy**

Is there a way to record the video and have it not be sped up, but instead mirror the real execution times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This discrepancy can occur if the Frames Per Second (FPS) rate of the recorded video is different from the actual execution speed of your tests. Fortunately, in Appium Python, **you can control the FPS rate of the recorded video using the videoFps parameter in the start_recording_screen() method.**

**By default, the FPS rate is set to 10 FPS**, which may result in a faster playback speed compared to the real-time execution of your tests. To address this issue, you can adjust the FPS rate to match the desired playback speed. Here's how you can do it:

```
fps = "60"
driver.start_recording_screen(videoFps=fps)
```

In the above code, we've adjusted the videoFps parameter to 60 FPS, but you can modify it according to your test requirements. By setting the FPS rate to match the real-time execution speed of your tests, the recorded video should mirror the actual execution times more accurately.

Try adjusting the FPS rate and re-run your tests to see if it resolves the issue of the recorded video being too fast compared to the real-time execution.

I suggest anyone to check the **documentation** here **(JSON Parameters section):** https://appium.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/commands/device/recording-screen/start-recording-screen/